# What does the << operator do with shifts farther than 32?

Tags: javascript, node.js

At node environment | javascript code :

```
1 << 33 ===  1 << 1 
// true
```

I know Number is stored in 32 bit. It in

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

After: << 33

```
1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000?
```

And:

```
1<< 35 === 1 << 3
```

Question: How does the `<<` operator work here?

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only. If you're looking for how JS numbers are stored in memory, please post a separate question (or search for one that already did ask this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) << operators how to work?

You can find the definition of `<<` [within the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (ECMA 262).

The key step for your question is:

> 11) Let *shiftCount* be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum `& 0x1F`.

This means the the 2nd operand cannot be greater than `31` (`0x1F`). If it is, it's reduced via bit masking before continuing:

```
(33 & 0x1f) === 1 // true
```

So:

```
1 << 33          // becomes...
1 << (33 & 0x1f) // becomes...
1 << 1
```

---

> 2) How is Numbers in the memory to stored?

A [number in JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value) is a:

> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754-2008 value

Comment: isn't the result of  `1<<33`  2?

Comment: @loxxy Yeah, it is. Both `1 << 1` and `1 << 33` result in `2`.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators:

> The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the low five bits will be used.

So `a<<b` when b is greater than or equal to 32, means `a<<(b&31)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `<<`, the shifting is *almost* circular. In other words, when you are shifting 32 bits, you get back the same number. Or

```
1 << x
```

is always equal

```
1 << x % 32 (% is the mod)
```

Therefore, `1 << 33 === 1 << 1` is always `true` because `33 % 32 == 1`.

Comment: That's not exactly true. What does get shifted out on the left won't get shifted in from the right.